# Sympy : How can I force factor() to factor minus one when it exists?

Tags: sympy

How is it possible to factor minus one ? (See the code below)

```
n=sympy.symbols("n",real=True)
expr=-2*n-2
sympy.factor(expr)
```

This code returns **-2(n+1)**.
But,

```
expr=-n-1
sympy.factor(expr)
```

does not return **-(n+1)**. Instead, **-n-1** is returned

While `sympy.factor_list(expr)` returns **(-1,[(n+1,1)])**.

So, does it exist a *factor()* option to have **-(n+1)** returned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factor_terms(-n - 1) -> -(n + 1)`